# Android onTouchListener stops receiving events when finger is moved up

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have a custom view with the following OnTouchListener assigned to it in my activity:

```
private OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("onTouch called.");
        System.out.println("x" + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
        return true;
    }
};
```

This registers and displays events in the log as expected, until the user moves their finger up or down more than a few pixels. After this, no touch events are passed to the listener until the user removes and reapplies their finger. However, using `adb shell getevent` shows that events are still being generated. An example of the LogCat output, with annotations, can be found at http://pastebin.com/7EBM2X4V.

The issue is not that the finger goes outside the bounds of the view.

Does anyone know why I have this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Well this might be old, but it still comes up in the search results.
It's possible to prevent the ScrollView from intercepting the touch events by doing this:

```
private OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
//our touch handling began, request the scrollview not to interact
scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
           System.out.println("Down");          
           System.out.println("x" + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
        }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
           System.out.println("Move");          
           System.out.println("x" + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
        }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
//re-enable it after we're done (finger goes up)
scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
           System.out.println("up");          
           System.out.println("x" + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: basically a good idea, but this prevents the scrollview from scrolling

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue is that the view is contained in a ScrollView. Removing the ScrollView fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the event into the onTouch like down, move or up for that you have to do like this way.

```
private OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
           System.out.println("Down");          
           System.out.println("x" + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
        }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
           System.out.println("Move");          
           System.out.println("x" + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
        }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
           System.out.println("up");          
           System.out.println("x" + event.getX() + ", y: " + event.getY());
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: No you don't. Even if I do change it to that, it still doesn't work properly.